# React redux state not updated in every screen, useSelector gets new state at Home Screen but gets previous state on another screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, useselector

I am working with React Redux, I can't understand why it brings the former state again.

actions.js

```js
export const SET_USER= "SET_USER";

export const setUser = user => ({
  type: SET_USER,
  payload: user
});
```

reducers.js

```js
import { SET_USER } from "./actions";

const initialState = {
  user: {
    name: '',
    profileId: ''
  }
};

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_USER: {
      return 
        ...state,
        user: action.payload
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default userReducer;
```

store.js

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import userReducer from './reducers';
import { createStore } from 'redux'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, userReducer)

export const store = createStore(persistedReducer)
export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```

Home.js

```
const user = useSelector(state => state.user);

<Text>{user.profileId}<Text>
```

SecondScreen.js

I refresh user data from server with user.profileId here

```js
const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
const [profileData, setProfileData] =useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Here I wait updated profileId", user.profileId)
  apiGetProfile();
}, []);

const apiGetProfile = async () => {
  mainAxios
      .get('profiles/' + user.profileId, {})
      .then(function (response) {
        setLoading(false)
        if (response.status == 200) {

          setProfileData(response.data)
        } 
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Settings.js

```
import { setUser} from './../../reduxStore/actions';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const Settings = ({ navigation }) => {
  const changeProfile = id => {     
    dispatch(setUser({ name: "New name", profileId: "new id" }))
  };

}
```

I change user `name` and `id` in settings screen with `dispatch`, then on `Home` screen I observe new values but then I move to `Second` screen I get former old values there.

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by "former state". If you change name several times Home screen shows the latest and Second screen shows previous change?

Comment: @dlitsman First user.profileId is 11111 when I login app I get 11111 in Home and SecondScreen than go to Settings and change user.profileId to 22222 go back Home user.profileId gives 22222 but when I navigate SecondScreen I get 11111 again, if I close and open app again I get 22222 on Second screen too

Comment: Is anything missing from the code for second screen? You seem to only use the user value inside the useEffect hook

Comment: The provided code example appears to be incomplete. Please [edit] to include all relevant code in your [mcve].

Comment: Edited second screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with you `useEffect` hook.

The second parameter of the hook is its dependency array - when this array is empty you are telling React to only run the hook on the first render cycle.

Changing your hook to the following should help:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Here I wait updated profileId",user.profileId )
}, [user.profileId]);
```

---

That said - it isn't clear if there is anything missing from your code. You only havea `console.log` in `useEffect` which isn't necessary (you don't need `useEffect` for this), and `useSelector` will trigger a re-render, so if you use `user.profileId` in JSX code I would expect it to update.

Comment: Thank you I updated code I want page refresh with new user api data

Comment: Thank you using user.profileId in the hook seems to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

**reducer.js**

```
    import { SET_USER } from "./actions";

    const initialState = {

      user:{
        name:'',
        profileId:''
      }
    };

    const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        
        case SET_USER: {
        
          return 
            user: action.payload
          };
        }
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }

    export default userReducer;
```

**Home.js**

```
const  user  = useSelector(state => state.user.profileId);
const [userId,setUserId]=useState(user);

  <Text>{userId}<Text>
```

**SecondScreen.js**

```
 const  user  = useSelector(state => state.user.profileId);

//  useEffect(() => {
    //console.log("Here I wait updated profileId",user.profileId )
  //}, []);//not required useEffect

const [userId,setUserId]=useState(user);

  <Text>{userId}<Text>
```

if you want to store multiple data then store array of object insted of simple string like this :

```
const initialState = {    |  const initialState = {
                          |
                          | 
  user:{                  |   user:[{               
    name:'',              |        name:'someName',
    profileId:''          |        profileId:111, 
  }                       |   }]
};                        | };
```

if you want multiple data then use spread operator in dispatch method like this:

```
case SET_USER: {               | case SET_USER: { 
      return                   | return {
        ...state,              | ...state,
        user: action.payload   | user: 
                                    [...state.user,action.payload],
      };                       |  }; 
    }                          | }
```

**temperory i have stored single data in your case ,now you can change whatever you want its very simple**

Comment: for multiple data I changed set_user with array tag like this user: [...state,action.payload], but I get error on dispatch(setUser({name:"updatedName",profileId:"updatedId"}))

Comment: dispatch(setUser([{name:"updatedName",profileId:"updatedId"}])) and reducer:-[...state.user,action.payload],

Answer (score 0):

You can direct use useSelector value.
No need to add useEffect

SecondScreen.js

```
<code>
 const  user  = useSelector(state => state.user.profileId);

//  useEffect(() => {
    //console.log("Here I wait updated profileId",user.profileId )
  //}, []);//not required useEffect
  console.log("user", user);

</code>
```

Comment: OP ***is*** using the `useSelector` hook. The `useEffect` hook usage also isn't in question here. The code you suggest now incorrectly console logs as an unintentional/unexpected side-effect ***because*** it's not using the `useEffect` hook.